# w3m to display image inline and quit

Tags: command-line, enlightenment, w3m

In a Lubuntu 16.04 system, `w3m` does display png and jpeg image files inline on a gnome terminal, but it enters the command mode, so the image only shows when you press some key (like down arrow, there's text meanwhile), and then you have to exit by pressing `q`. Is there any option to show images inline precisely like Terminology's tycat command does? So it shows and you can keep tying commands, and the image stays there, and scrolls as needed.

Comment: This post gives some more insight on a possible solution, based on the libraries used by w3m. http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/01/images-in-terminal.html